# Idea как найти утечку памяти java

Tags: java, память

Читаю файлы с диска. Большие файлы.

Загоняю данные в массивы чар и стринг билдеры. По завершении все обнуляю, но занимаемая память не освобождается.

Подскажите, есть какая-нибудь утилита, которая может помочь отследить какие объекты занимают больше всего памяти ?

Звонил System.gc() не помогает.
Спасибо.

Comment: https://visualvm.github.io

Comment: Eclipse Memory analizer https://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Answer (score 0):

Проблему вроде как решил, при помощи задания параметров JVM о размере используемой памяти. Java набирала себе огромную кучу памяти(heap), и не использовала её.
Не знаю правда, как "оно" поведет себя вне IDE
Спасибо за ссылку на VisualVM

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Java набирала себе огромную кучу памяти(heap), и не использовала её` нормальная ситуация, проще взять память у ОС и держать при себе -- может еще пригодиться